# Android recyclerview scroll to a position which is in between two items of my adapter?

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview

Hello everyone this question is i am having from a lot of time but i didn't get any solution, so the problem is in recycler view how can i use scrollto to scroll to an adapter location which is in partial view that is suppose i want to scroll the user to the item location which is in the middle of 10th and 11th item of my adapter now how to scoll to at that position, apps do this but i dont know how to do this task so anybody if anyone have any idea about this please share soem light on it also if it is a trivial problem please be patient, i am a beginner in android so don't know much about this

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you can get access to a particular itemView View at the specified position, then you can use `scrollTo(0, itemView.getBottom())`, where the bottom of the itemView the space below the first item and above the second item.

Comment: what is the difference between scrollto and scrollby and also inside onScrolled method how to find how much pixels i have move down when i have scrolled ??

Comment: scrollTo is scroll to an absolute distance,but now recyclerView did not support scrollTo() but scrollBy is scroll to a relative distance. you can use scrollHorizontallyBy() to calculate the distance that you had scrolled